# How to get readonly field value from base generic abstract class

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I would like to retrieve readonly field value `_classC` from base generic abstract class `Base<A, B>`
.

**What I have tried**

[FieldInfo.GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=net-5.0) must be used certainly, but I can't guess the right parameter.

Thought the instance of the derived class would be okay.

```cs
var derived = new Derived();
var baseType = typeof(Base<,>);

var classCField = baseType
  .GetField("_classC", BindingFlags.NonPublic 
    | BindingFlags.Static 
    | BindingFlags.Instance 
    | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

classCField.GetValue(derived);
```

**The error I get**

> InvalidOperationException: Late bound operations cannot be performed on fields with types for which Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Is that even possible?

**Type definitions**

```cs
public interface IBase<A, B>
    where A : class
    where B : class, new()
{
    
}

public class ClassD
{
    
}

public class ClassC
{
    
}

public abstract class Base<A, B> : IBase<A, B>
    where A : class
    where B : class, new()
    {
        private readonly ClassC _classC = new ClassC();
    }

public class Derived : Base<ClassC, ClassD>
{
}
```

Comment: [DotNetFiddle of situation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTpBMC)...

Comment: I think it's because you're not using the actual base type of `Derived` but rather `Base<,>`, which has no type parameters. If you use `derived.GetType().BaseType`, it throws a different exception: ```[System.FieldAccessException: Attempt by method 'Program.Main()' to access field 'Base`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>._classC' failed.]``` [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NVuHkz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this :

```
var field = typeof(Derived).BaseType.GetField("_classC", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
var value = field.GetValue(derived);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your first error is caused by using an open generic type, you need a constructed one (e.g. `Base<ClassC, ClassD>`). The next error is that your field isn't static.

As for a repro: it's DotNetFiddle that runs with an outdated trust model regarding reflection. On [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/ve5NW8) this runs just fine:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var derived = new Derived();
        var baseType = derived.GetType().BaseType;
        
        var classCField = baseType.GetField("_classC", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                
        Console.WriteLine(classCField.GetValue((Base)derived));
    }
}

public class ClassC
{
}

public abstract class Base//<A, B> : IBase<A, B> where A : class where B : class, new()
{
    private readonly ClassC _classC = new ClassC();
}

public class Derived : Base//<ClassC, ClassD>
{
}
```